# Link on picture to another website in lightbox2

Tags: html, hyperlink, lightbox2

I have lightbox2 installed on my website, and it works fine. But now i would like to be able to when a picture is shown in the gallery, i would like the user to be able to click on the picture, that then takes them to another website. Is this possible?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <a href="projekt/grevtureg/fore1.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('img1','','projekt/grevtureg/grevtureg2.jpg',1)"><img src="projekt/grevtureg/grevtureg.jpg" id="img1" class="fade" /></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/fore2.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/fore2.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor1.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor2.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor3.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor4.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor5.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor6.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor7.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor8.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor9.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor10.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a><a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor11.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Just work with `http://` in the `<a>` tags.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

```
<a href="http://www.google.de" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('img1','','http://www.google.de/grevtureg2.jpg',1)">Hello world!</a>
```

> This was the single required attribute for anchors defining a
>   hypertext source link, but is no longer required in HTML5. Omitting
>   this attribute creates a placeholder link. The href attribute
>   indicates the link target, either a URL or a URL fragment. A URL
>   fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which specifies an
>   internal target location (an ID) within the current document. URLs are
>   not restricted to Web (HTTP)-based documents. URLs might use any
>   protocol supported by the browser. For example, file, ftp, and mailto
>   work in most user agents.

optional: add id attribute (e.g.: id="myLink") then add script ->

```
document.querySelector("#myLink").addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.de";
});
```

Comment: Hi well i would like the gallery to open, and then after like the 4th image, i would like it to be possible to click on the image and open up for ex. google.com, i do not need to do the swap-image etc, that is just for the first picture on the website. Could you perhaps give me the code for the images inside the lightbox gallery (the one where you specify the "data-lightbox="grevtureg". Thanks for your help!

Comment: simply add http:// tag in the href attribute and if you want to open the link in a new tab set target="_blank"

Comment: The thing is that in the a href attribute i have the picture that is shown, so it does not work. Where do i put the picture?

here is the code: <a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor2.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a> 

I would like that when this image is shown, the user can click on it and go directly to another webpage.

Comment: <a href="projekt/grevtureg/grevturegatan_stor2.jpg" data-lightbox="grevtureg"><img src=".....jpg"></a>

Comment: I might seem a little bit dumb now, but now you have linked the picture above in the href, and you have another img src, where do i put the actual link to google.com? where the "grevturegatan_stor2.jpg" img, is?

Comment: Here is my website: http://kompaktbygg.se/ if you press on "projekt" you will get to the projekt area, the first project is the gallery i would like to on for ex. the 4th picture (inside the gallery), be able to press on the picture to go directly to another website.

Comment: Then do a <a href="url of another website" target="_blank"><img...></a> for the fourth picture. (?)

Comment: Well now as you see if you go into my website, the picture is not inside the gallery, it gets put outside of the gallery and screws up the whole page.

Comment: I have written the code like this: <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="projekt/grevtureg/houzz.png" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a>

Comment: the href attribute in the a tag must contain the prefix "http://" to become a valid url.

Comment: Well if you look on the webpage as i said, it seems that it is not possible to have the link inside the gallery, the picture gets put outside of the gallery. Now i have been able to get the picture inside of the gallery, but the links does not work (it just moves forward to the next picture).

please see the following code: <a href="projekt/grevtureg/houzz.png" data-lightbox="grevtureg" a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>

Comment: Then do following: add id attribute (e.g.: id="myLink") to the <img> and then add script: document.querySelector("#myLink").addEventListener("click", function(e){ window.location.href = "http:// www.google.de": });

Comment: Hi, I have done the following now: In the HTML i have put the this code:

<a href="projekt/grevtureg/houzz.png" id="houzz" data-lightbox="grevtureg"></a>

In the head area, i have written this script: 

    <script> 
    document.querySelector("#houzz").addEventListener("click", function(e){ window.location.href = "http:// www.google.com": });
    </script> 

It still does not work, when the picture is shown in the gallery, it does not link to google.com, any tips? :)

Comment: I'm very sorry, but this does still not work. The picture is not included in the gallery, it just gets outside of the code.